# What are some good resources for the aesthetics of mathematics?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, reference-request, aesthetics

Many mathematicians often equate mathematics to art and find a deep beauty in its method, results, and ideas. The classic example of this romanticism is captured by G.H. Hardy's *A Mathematician's Apology*, for instance. However, it seems like the aesthetics of mathematics are much less studied than the aesthetics of more traditional conceptions of art. For example, in his 1938 *Modes of Thought*, Whitehead writes:

> Also the feeling, widespread among mathematicians, that some proofs are more beautiful than others, should excite the attention of philosophers.
>
> I suggest to you that the analogy between aesthetics and logic is one of the undeveloped topics of philosophy.

Has this changed significantly since Whitehead's time? **Are there any standard reference for the philosophical study of aesthetics in math, or particularly relevant articles/books?** If the field has developed enough to have different schools then I would also appreciate a brief summary of the schools with a representative reference to the ideas typical of said schools.

Note that I am asking for the philosophical discussions of why math is (found to be) beautiful, and why some features of mathematics are (perceived to be) more beautiful than others. I am less interested in works by mathematicians describing the specific things they find beautiful (otherwise I would have asked on math.SE), unless they also advance a philosophy along with their personal tastes.

Comment: I gave some references in reply to a [previous question](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/has-there-been-any-philosophical-investigation-into-the-role-of-aesthetics-in-ma).

Comment: I'm wondering if we should merge the two questions, they really are very close?

Comment: @JosephWeissman they are very close, and my bad for not noticing the previous question. I am really asking for references though, in particular surveys and overviews. Maybe back and forth links is enough? But it is your call.

Answer (score 3):

Relevant articles:

- David Wells, [Are these the most beautiful?](http://www.gwern.net/docs/1990-wells.pdf) 
  See also the references given there.
- Tommy Dreyfus and Theodore Eisenberg, On the Aesthetics 
  of Mathematical Thought
- Bettina Heintz, Die Innenwelt der Mathematik.
- Boris Koichu, Efim Katz and Abraham Berman, [What is a beautiful problem?](http://www.emis.de/proceedings/PME31/3/113.pdf)
- Nathalie Sinclair, [The Roles of the Aesthetic in Mathematical Inquiry](http://www.sfu.ca/~nathsinc/MTLSinclair.pdf)
- Don Zagier, [Die Schönheit der Zahlen](http://www.mpg.de/5021579/W001_Zur-Sache_012-017.pdf)

---

*Entfliehen nicht die Grazien, wo Integrale ihre Hälse recken?* 
(Ludwig Bolzmann)

Comment: Could you add a sentence or two about each reference to give us an idea of what main ideas they capture? That would make this list much more useful, at least for me.